# Error installing Buster for Ghost

Tags: python-3.x, pip, ghost-blog

I am getting an error while installing on Windows 7 [Buster](https://github.com/axitkhurana/buster) a brute force static site generator for Ghost.

I am installing it using [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip):
`$ pip install buster`

Then an error pops up:

```
Downloading/unpacking async==0.6.1 (from buster)
Downloading async-0.6.1.tar.gz
Running setup.py (path:C:\Users\oem\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_oem\async\setup.py)     egg_info for package async
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 17, in 
File "C:\Users\oem\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_oem\async\setup.py", line 24
print "Ignored failure when building extensions, pure python modules will be used instead"
^SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 17, in
File "C:\Users\oem\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_oem\async\setup.py", line 24
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue for my website.

Your python version is too high. Download and install python 2.7, and you should be good.

You also need to install wget for windows.

Comment: you're right downgrading to Python 2.7.x solves this problem. Be also aware that Ghost version > 0.4 causes some other issues when used with Buster (not fully copying images, wrong css and js file names, etc).

Comment: I also had to install pip/ I downloaded this file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py and ran it from the command line.